# Split string in terminal and assign them to variables in android

Tags: android, variables, unix

I'm trying to read a file using terminal and then split the string on each line to $var1 and $var2.

Is there a way to assign $var1 and $var2 to a java variable?

Answer (score 0):

Java variable storage and shell variable storage are entirely separate.

If you still need to do this, write the variables to a text file. Open that file in your Java code, read the values out of it, and assign them to the Java variables. It's long-winded, but it will work, if you do it right.